Relationship between f test and t -test
I am working on a problem where I should derive the t test statistic from an f test given an ANOVA table (below). From my understanding, when we conduct an f-test we are using the variance to determine whether there is a difference in a group, while for the t-test we are comparing individual mean differences, and the t-test can be obtained by taking the square root of the f-test.
So, if I wanted to find the t statistic for the interaction term below of pesticide and plant.type, can I simply just take the sqaure root of the ftest given in the table, if so how could I identify what the degrees of freedom would be for this t-statistic? I'm just trying to understand the relationship between the two better.

